# command to open Network Manager or system settings in lubuntu?

Tags: networking, network-manager, system-settings, gsettings

What is command to open system settings or network manger in lubuntu, like gnome-control-center in ubuntu, i also tried unity-contorl-center, but nothing work..

Comment: Have you tried `nm-connection-editor`?

Comment: I tried, but it not opens netowrk manager settings, it open only already configured networks

Comment: I don't have `lubuntu`, so I have to ask you run a command to see whats going on. what is the output of this command: `apropos network | grep -i manager`

Comment: After running `nm-connection-editor` aren't you able to add new network?  you should see something like [this](www.linuxprobe.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/nm-connection-editor.png) which allows you to add new networks.

Comment: I allow to add network, but I used to add auto detected mobilebroadband data card. its not auto detected in that nm-connection-editor.